# Как изменить список в C#?

Tags: c#

Как мне сделать изменение списка? Мне нужно отдавать в конечном итоге исходных список и изменённый.

Я подумал, что это должно выполняться следующим образом:

```
        public IReadOnlyList<SpanDto> ConvertSpans(ref List<SpanDto> spanDtos, UnitSystem unitSystem)
    {
        foreach (var spanDto in  spanDtos)
        {
            if (unitSystem == UnitSystem.Metric)
            {
                spanDto.Length /= 3.28084;

                spanDto.NoLoading.Sag /= 3.28084;
                spanDto.NoLoading.SpanPercent = spanDto.NoLoading.Sag / spanDto.Length;
                spanDto.NoLoading.Tension *= 4.448222 / 1000;

                spanDto.AtLoading.Sag /= 3.28084;
                spanDto.AtLoading.SpanPercent = spanDto.AtLoading.Sag / spanDto.Length * 100;
                spanDto.AtLoading.HSag /= 3.28084;
                spanDto.AtLoading.VSag /= 3.28084;
                spanDto.AtLoading.Tension *= 4.448222 / 1000;
            }
        }

        return spanDtos;
    }
```

По итогу мне возвращается как изменённых одинаковых списка

Comment: А какой из списков должен быть изменённым - тот, который возвращается `return` или тот, который был передан через параметры? Как-то это странно выглядит, что передаётся `ref`, в этом случае вы можете и новый изменённый список вернуть и тот, который передан через параметр сделать другим списком. `ref` вообще нужно очень осторожно использовать, а лучше вообще не использовать, тем более когда в `C#` давно есть кортежи и прочие способы вернуть сразу несколько значений из функции. Раньше его использовали именно чтобы возвращать из функции несколько значений.

Comment: @CrazyElf, мне нужно вернуть изменённый список, который я передаю в аргументе. К сожалению, ref и out я не очень хорошо изучил и подумал, что они будут тут уместны

Comment: @CrazyElf, подскажите, пожалуйста как мне вернуть исходный список(передаётся в аргумент) и изменённый

Comment: Ну вы тогда уберите `ref`, он всё-равно тут не нужен. Непонятно зачем вам возвращать вообще исходный список - ведь он есть уже у того, кто вызвал функцию. А новый список вам нужно создать, заполнить его **новыми** же элементами, в которые вы скопируете (и нужным образом поменяете) поля элементов старого списка.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так это должно выглядеть, насколько я понял ваш вопрос:

```
public IReadOnlyList<SpanDto> ConvertSpans(List<SpanDto> spanDtos, UnitSystem unitSystem)
{
    ret = new List<SpanDto>();
    foreach (var spanDto in spanDtos)
    {
        var item = new SpanDto();
        // тут заполняете поля теми данными, которые не меняются
        // ...
        if (unitSystem == UnitSystem.Metric)
        {
            // тут заполняете изменяющиеся поля
            // с использованием данных из spanDto
            // ...
        }
        ret.Add(item);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Исходный список есть у тех, кто его передал как параметр. А новый список вы вернёте из функции.